# Python child class inherit and override from arbitrary parent

Tags: python, class, inheritance, scikit-learn, subclass

I'm working with sklearn estimators, which inherit from sklearn.base.BaseEstimator and have a fairly standard interface.  An example of what I want to do is override the .fit() and .predict() methods to regress against log-transformed targets like so:

```
Estimator = sklearn.some_regression_estimator

class LogFit(Estimator):
    """subclass the sklearn regression estimator to fit and predict using 
       log-transformed target variable
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(kwargs)

    def fit(X, y=None, **kwargs):
        super().fit(X, np.log(y), **kwargs)
        return self

    def predict(X):
       return np.exp(super().predict(X))
```

I don't necessarily know in advance which estimator will be used, only that it will behave according to sklearn estimator conventions.  I also don't want to re-write the above subclass for each possible estimator, and multiple inheritance seems incorrect since each instance of `LogFit` is only inheriting from a single parent.

I get that I could write a wrapper class (then subclass *it* with the over-ridden fit() and predict() methods) like e.g.:

```
class EstimatorWrapper():
    """Wrapper class that has an estimator as a property"""

    def __init__(self, estimator_instance):
        self.estimator = estimator_instance
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.fit(X, y, **kwargs)
        return self
   ...
```

but at this point I now have to take on the responsibility of making sure the EstimatorWrapper class behaves just like the base estimator class so I can use the LogFit versions of fit() and predict() without the rest of sklearn's machinery knowing the difference.  Here again, if I don't know which particular methods/properties exist in each possible estimator_instance, it seems I'd have to hack in a way for EstimatorWrapper() to dynamically define its properties, when all I really want to do is tweak the fit() and predict() function behaviors.

Am I missing a simple way to write a child class that doesn't know its parent class until instantiation, or is that fundamentally not allowed?  I can't find any examples of how to do the former

Answer (score 1):

It goes around the question, but there's a third option that might be good to explore here: [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html), which wraps a regressor and lets you define *forward* and *inverse* transformation functions to apply to the target variable.

Here's an example using `np.log1p` and inverse `np.expm1`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

X = np.array([-0.890,-0.798,-0.610,-0.502,-0.450,-0.382,-0.342,-0.282,-0.226,-0.158,-0.0500,0.106,0.202,0.322,0.418,0.482,0.530,0.590,0.666,0.754,0.834,0.914,0.970,-0.694,-0.762,-0.782,-0.854,-0.850,-0.658,-0.666,-0.482,-0.506,-0.398,-0.478,-0.350,-0.410,-0.334,-0.378,-0.314,-0.346,-0.230,-0.250,-0.150,-0.146,-0.0500,-0.0700,0.0180,0.0300,0.110,0.178,0.214,0.290,0.318,0.406,0.422,0.482,0.478,0.486,0.546,0.566,0.674,0.658,0.702,0.726,0.838,0.882,0.950,0.934,0.882,0.786,0.786,0.718,0.682,0.570,0.502,0.426,0.234,-0.470,-0.430,-0.390,-0.354]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0.663,0.679,0.675,0.627,0.535,0.331,0.171,0.0111,-0.169,-0.273,-0.421,-0.497,-0.505,-0.457,-0.361,-0.237,-0.141,-0.0129,0.0751,0.127,0.143,0.147,0.143,0.691,0.723,0.671,0.707,0.611,0.727,0.595,0.683,0.567,0.571,0.375,0.391,0.255,0.255,0.0831,0.0991,-0.0689,-0.0729,-0.225,-0.217,-0.309,-0.293,-0.453,-0.417,-0.533,-0.433,-0.577,-0.393,-0.489,-0.341,-0.421,-0.313,-0.353,-0.109,-0.117,-0.169,-0.0369,-0.141,0.159,0.0991,0.139,0.155,0.0511,0.231,0.123,0.187,0.00707,0.139,-0.0249,-0.00893,-0.205,-0.121,-0.261,-0.417,0.527,0.491,0.391,0.0591]).ravel()
plt.scatter(X, y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)


for regressor in [DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3), MLPRegressor(max_iter=500), SVR()]:

    regr = TransformedTargetRegressor(
        regressor=regressor,
        func=np.log1p,
        inverse_func=np.expm1,
    )
    regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    score = round(regr.score(X_test, y_test), 3)

    # Some visualization
    data = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), num=250).reshape(-1, 1)
    reg_line = regr.predict(data)
    plt.plot(data, reg_line, label=f"R2={score}, {regr.regressor.__class__.__name__}")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Plot showing regressors fit to 2D data using TransformedTargetRegressor]